# React-router: How to resize header after navigating to new page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react-router application with a header component that takes up the full height of the page when at the '/home' path. When I navigate to a new path, '/foo', I need the header's height to change.

When I load either page directly by typing the url into the browser, it has the correct height:

- 100vh for localhost:3000/home
- 15vh for localhost:3000/foo

However when I navigate from /home to /foo with the below code, the URL changes correctly, but the DOM does not re-render. The header still has a height of 100vh and the DOM does not contain the Foo component.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/home' component={null}/>
          <Route path='/foo' component={Foo}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**Home.js**

```
const Home = () => {
    // ... some more code
    const navigate = useCallback(to => {
        history.push(to);
    }, []);
    // ... some more code
};
```

**Header.js**

```
const Header = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const style = pathname === '/home'
        ? { height: '100vh'}
        : { height: '15vh'}
    return (
        <div style={style}>
            { /* ...some more code */ }
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Foo.js**

```
const Foo = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Foo...
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is not re-rendering because it is outside Switch. So, changing the route will not re-trigger the header.
You will have to import the header in the Home and Foo component so that it re-renders on changing the path.

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer because it explained what was wrong with my code. However, what I ended up doing was just using redux to keep track of a isExpanded variable, so that navigation and resizing logic was seperate

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that when changing the path it's not triggering a redraw.

I'd recommend using React-Routers 'Route' component within the header (assuming the extra div isn't an issue).

So it will look like this:

```
const HeaderInternal = () => {
  return { /* ... some header code */ }
}
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <>
          <Route path='/home'><div style={{ height: '100vh'}}><HeaderInternal /> </div></Route>
          <Route path='/foo'><div style={{ height: '15vh'}}><HeaderInternal /> </div></Route>
        </>
    );
};
```

I haven't directly tested this, but it the Route component should enforce a redraw whenever you switch pages. HeaderInternal is just to be DRY, but if you had a single component, you can skip it.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but this unfortunately did not work for me